# When unlocking the Onion Knight, do already-mastered jobs count towards its job level?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics

I understand that:

- The Onion Knight job is unlocked when you've raised both Squire and Chemist to job level 6.
- The Onion Knight doesn't raise its job level using JP. Rather, for every two jobs you master, the Onion Knight's job level goes up by one. Squire, Chemist, Dark Knight and Mime don't count.

So my question is: does the Onion Knight always start at Level 1? Or could it start at level N, if I already have 2N jobs mastered when I unlock Onion Knight?

Comment: Two notes about the Onion Knight: 1) Squire, Chemist, Dark Knight, and Mime job mastery don't count, 2) Onion Knight job level increases by one for every two jobs you master.

Comment: Thanks. Do the jobs already mastered before you unlock Onion Knight count, so long as they're not Squire, Chemist, Dark Knight, or Mime?

Comment: That I don't know: I'm pretty sure they do, but I can't find confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your Onion Knight's level can start out higher than Level 1.  The level of the OK is not accumulated but is, rather, strictly calculated by the number of jobs mastered (not counting the Squire, Chemist, Dark Knight and Mime classes.)

I can't find a source for this but I recall discovering this late in my game file ages ago.